# Make username out of email and check for duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to take the email, remove everything after @ and then check if there is no duplicates and if there are duplicate add number to username. 
I can't get right second part. Maybe you can help me to figure it out why its not working.

```
$username1 = explode( '@', $usermane );
$username=  $username1[0];


   $usersql = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_nicename LIKE '$username%'";
   $usercnt = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,$usersql));  

// If username username1 username2 etc already exists
    if ($usercnt >= 1) {
        $num = ++$usercnt;             // Increment $usercnt by 1
        $username = $username . $num;  // Add number to username
    }
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: what's the problem you are facing right now ? also you want to check if username after adding number exists or not?

Comment: I can't create the account with the email which begins with same name for example info@example.com, I need to add to "INFO" number that if there is "info" it should create info1 after info2 and so on.

Comment: TreyBake can you please explain your answer in more details I could not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are increasing `$usercnt`, while you actually want to increase `num`, to add that to your username. Use `strval()` to convert an Integer to a String.
Try:

```
if ($usercnt >= 1) {
    $num = $usercnt + 1;             // Num = Usercount + 1
    $username = $username . strval($num);  // Add number to username
}
```